# Trying to split a text file into multiple text files in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to get this code to split an input file into two files. I want the code to split so that one new file contains all the odd characters and the other file contains all the even characters. My code gives me no errors and it produces two new files but the two new files contain nothing in them. I am wondering what is wrong with my code(I am sure there is a lot wrong with it). I am still pretty new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void split(char sourceFile[], char destFile1[], char destFile2[]) {
    int chars = 0;
    ifstream sFile;
    sFile.open(sourceFile);
    ofstream file1;
    file1.open(destFile1);
    ofstream file2;
    file2.open(destFile2);

    while (!sFile.eof()) {
        sFile.read(sourceFile + chars, 1);

        cout << sourceFile[chars];
        if (chars % 2 == 0) {
            file1 << sourceFile[chars];
        } else {
            file2 << sourceFile[chars];
        }
        chars++;


    }
}

int main() {
    split("text.txt", "one.txt", "two.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know this will never be true, don't you: `chars % 2 == 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with it (as you said)

1) All your files are `ifstream`, if you want to output to a file use `ofstream`.

2) You should not attempt to use the file names as variables for your code. Just declare a new char variable.

3) Use get not read to read single characters.

4) Test for end of file correctly.

5) Don't close the files inside the loop, in fact don't close the files *at all*, it will happen automatically when you exit the function.

6) What on earth is `chars%2 == 5` about? It will never be true.

Putting that together

```
char ch;
while (sFile.get(ch))
{
    if (chars % 2 == 0)
        file1 << ch;
    else
        file2 << ch;
    chars++;
}
```

Comment: You have to close the output files explicitly, since you have to check their state after the close, to ensure that everything is correctly written.

Comment: Thanks for all the help by the way. I was finally able to figure it out. After all of you helping me it was still not working. Turns out I misspelled my test program :/

Answer (score 1):

Some very serious problems:

- You're loop control is meaningless.  It's not well defined
  when 'istream::eof()' becomes true, but when reading byte by
  byte, as you are doing, it will probably cause you to enter the
  loop one more time than you want.
- A related issue is that you *don't* verify that the read
  succeeded.  The success of the read should be your loop control.
- You're reading into a character literal, which is undefined
  behavior (and will crash on a lot of systems); after enough
  reads, you're reading beyond the end of the literal, into 
  undefined memory.  You really should use a local buffer for the
  read.
- You don't do any error checking.  At the very least, you
  should verify that you've successfully opened the files, and you
  should close the output files, and check their status after the
  close, to be sure that the writes have worked.

I'd probably use something along the lines:

```
void
split( std::string const& source, 
       std::string const& dest1,
       std::string const& dest2 )
{
    std::istream in( source.c_str() );
    if ( ! in.is_open() ) {
        //  Cannot open source...
    }
    std::ostream out1( source.c_str() );
    if ( ! out1.is_open() ) {
        //  Cannot create dest1
    }
    std::ostream out2( source.c_str() );
    if ( ! out2.is_open() ) {
        //  Cannot create dest2
    }
    std::ostream* currentOut = &out1;
    std::ostream* otherOut = &out2;
    char ch;
    while ( in.get( ch ) ) {
        currentOut->put( ch );
        std::swap( currentOut, otherOut );
    }
    out1.close();
    if ( !out1 ) {
        //  Write error on dest1...
    }
    out2.close();
    if ( !out2 ) {
        //  Write error on dest2...
    }
}
```

(As you can see, the actual loop which does the copying is
extremely simple.  Most of the code is involved in error
handling.)

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is misleading!  The file close() calls are *inside* the loop.

And: `i % 2 == 5` is never true.  How about `if (i % 2 == 0) { ... } else { ... }` ?

Comment: As I understood it, the bad indentation obscures the wrong placement of the close() thus making the program fail.  And the faulty second if was a problem in itself.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a ';' and misspelled 'sourcFile'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void split(char sourceFile[], char destFile1[], char destFile2[])
{
int chars = 0;

ifstream sFile;
sFile.open (sourceFile);

ofstream file1;
file1.open (destFile1);

ofstream file2;
file2.open (destFile2);

while (!sFile.eof())
{
    sFile.read(sourceFile+chars,1); // forgot ';'

    cout << sourceFile[chars];
    if (chars % 2 == 0)
    {
        file1<< sourceFile[chars];
    }
    else if(chars % 2 == 5)
    {
        file2 << sourceFile[chars]; // misspelled 'sourcFile'
    }
    chars++;

sFile.close();
file1.close();
file2.close();
}

}

int main()
{
split("text.txt", "one.txt", "two.txt");
return 0;
}
```

Haven't tested the output though. If it doesn't work, could you give us the inputfiles to try for ourselves?

Comment: read OP again; "_My code gives me no errors (...) I am wondering what is wrong with my code(I am sure there is a lot wrong with it)_". Everything said here is an actual problem. All other problems have already been adressed.

Comment: One problem is that **of course** the code posted isn't the real code. The OP claims the code compiles so the missing semi colon and mispelling are because he's typed the code in instead of cut and paste.

Comment: Haven't thought of that possibility. Was just trying to help. Should I delete this post (I'm pretty new at SO)?

Comment: @MartenBE I wouldn't worry about it. People not posting the actual code they're having problems with is all too common unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question but a somewhat compact version of a program implementing the desired goal:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    typedef std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> oit;
    unsigned int chars(0);
    std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(
                      std::ifstream("text.txt") >> std::noskipws),
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
                  std::bind([=](oit _1, oit _2, char c) mutable {
                          *(chars++ % 2? _1: _2)++ = c; },
                      oit(std::ofstream("one.txt") << std::dec),
                      oit(std::ofstream("two.txt") << std::dec),
                      std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

Comment: My version is more compact:-) (except that it does some error checking).  An elegant solution, however, would be to use a special output iterator which switches between the two files, and then use `std::copy`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, you solution also does something different: My understanding is that based on the `char`s value it should be sent to a different destination. Looking at the current state of the question this isn't quite right, though. I'll fix this...

Comment: @JamesKanze: Using a custom iterator would be quite involved. Clearly doable but I'd think it would take more code and may end up being readable. I prefer to use interesting techniques when answering apparent homework assignments (if it isn't a homework assignment, I think my technique uses a few interesting bits to learn from).

Comment: A custom iterator from scratch would require a lot of code.  (Although output iterators are a lot easier than the others.)  But perhaps using Boost::iterators would make it a viable solution.